# ECC Memory: Options available

Tags: memory

In my understanding, the memory is either non-ecc or ecc. The ECC corrects 1 bit errors and detects 2 bit.

**1) When the memory detects a 2 bit error, what happens?**

The ECC is divided in Registered (also kown as Buffered) ECC and Unbuffered ECC. There is also a Fully Buffered memory type.

**2) What's the difference between fully buffered and buffered memory?**

**3) Load-Reduce DIMM?**

Comment: Is this for a school project?

Comment: No, I am buying a server.

Comment: I think 'buffered' is an older term for registered memory. Registered memory has a register between the DRAM and the memory controller, which reduces the electrical load on the controller. This adds stability. I think buffered and fully buffered are the same thing, but either way I'm pretty sure it's called registered now...Here's a bit on load reduced DIMM --> http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/L/LRDIMM.html